# Multiple Variable in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to send 2 variable from my comobox but is does not work, it only works when I send 1 here is the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".clase").hide();
$(".ruta").change(function(){
var id=$(".rutas").val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "asientos.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
        $(".clase").show();
       $(".clase").change(function(){
      var id=$(".rutas").val();
      var cla=$(".clase").val();
      var dataString = 'id='+ id;
     var data = 'cla'+ cla;
$.ajax
  ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "asientos.php",
          data: dataString,data,
         cache: false,
         success: function(html)
{
        $(".asientos").html(html);
}
           });
        });
       }
    }); 
  });
});
```

Now here is my html only showing the combo part cause i have multiple components in the form

```
<label class="ruta">Rutas </label> <select name="rutas" id="rutas" class="rutas" >
<?php   include 'rutas.php';   ?>
</select>
<label class="clase">Clases </label><select name="clase" id="clase" class="clase">
<option value="A">Clase Ejecutiva</option>;
<option value="B">Clase Media</option>;
<option value="C">Clase Economico</option>;
</select>
```

In the first combo I am Retrieving data from database and the second combo I inputted the data, now i need that both values from each combo save to the variables I have in my Php file in order to fill the third combo.

Comment: In the first combo I am Retrieving data from database and the second combo I inputted the data, now i need that both values from each combo save to the variables I have in my Php file in order to fill the third combo.

Comment: Chk the answer given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are using two ajax request here, you can only use second request and if you want to send two select box value by using ajax than this will not work:

```
var dataString = 'id='+ id; 
var data = 'cla'+ cla;
```

You can just simply use:

```
var dataString = 'id='+ id+'&cla='+cla;
```

In ajax, no need to use like that:

```
data: dataString,data,
```

you can just use like that:

```
data: dataString,
```